# Adicionar um controlador de size da pagina

Tags: javascript, html, css

Gostaria de saber como posso fazer esse controlador de size da pagina ao redimensionar ele ser dinâmico como [nesse exemplo](https://www.w3schools.com/css/tryit.asp?filename=tryresponsive_mediaquery) do w3schools.
Quero adicionar isso no meu site e credito que seja com JavaScript posso deixar essa informação dinâmica ao clicar e arrastar mais não consegui encontrar nada.

Comment: O que faz esse exemplo funcionar é o `media query`, mais em concreto o `@media only screen and (max-width: 500px) {` que recebe o css a utilizar quando a página tem menos de 500 pixeis de largura. É só meter la o css para esse caso. Ou trocar o numero para outra dimensão que queira

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tirado diretamente do [W3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/Jsref/event_onresize.asp), o evento `onresize` no body é executado sempre que a tela é aumentada ou diminuída chamando o `myFunction()` que atualiza o DOM exibindo a largura e altura da tela.

```html
<html>
<body onresize="myFunction()">

<p>Try to resize the browser window to display the windows height and width.</p>

<p id="demo"></p>

<p><strong>Note:</strong> this example will not work properly in IE8 and earlier. IE8 and earlier do not support the outerWidth/outerHeight propery of the window object.</p>

<script>

function myFunction() {
    var w = window.outerWidth;
    var h = window.outerHeight;
    var txt = "Window size: width=" + w + ", height=" + h;
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = txt;
}
myFunction();
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Perfeito!!!  era isso mesmo. Muito Obrigado